# Rename json Object name in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

How do I rename Object name from Cars to automobiles?
I tried using ObjectRenameKeys but it works on the properties within objects not the object name itself.

Original:

```
"Cars": [
                {

                    "Part": 1
                },
                {

                    "Part": 2
                },
                {

                    "Part": 3
                }
            ],
Expected: 

"Automobiles": [
                {

                    "Part": 1
                },
                {

                    "Part": 2
                },
                {

                    "Part": 3
                }
            ],
```

Comment: You seem to have properties inside objects ... otherwise these are syntax errors. Also what do you mean with `ObjectRenameKeys` ?

Comment: For your reference-https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-rename-keys

Answer (score 3):

You can't really rename properties....just copy Cars  and then delete it:

```
myObject.Automobiles = myObject.Cars;
delete myObject.Cars;
```